# Create environment variable with dot in the current environment

Tags: bash

I know that you can create environment variables with the command `env`.

For example:

```
env A.B=D bash
```

The problem is for env a command is required thus creating a new subprocess.

Comment: Whatever program `env` starts reuses the same process (that is, `env` calls `exec` to replace itself with the program it runs).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bash does not allow environment variables with non-alphanumeric characters in their names (aside from <kbd>_</kbd>). While the environment may contain a line such as `A.B=D`, there is no requirement that a shell be able to make use of it, and bash will not. Other shells may be more flexible.

Utilities which make use of oddly-named environment variables are discouraged, but some may exist. You will need to use `env` to create such an environment variable. You could avoid the subprocess with `exec env bash` but it won't save you much in the way of time or resources.

Comment: This bash restriction is documented in the definition of `name`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions

Answer (score 6):

rici has the correct answer. To demonstrate the difference required to access such environment entries, bash requires you to parse the environment as text:

```
$ env A.B=C perl -E 'say $ENV{"A.B"}'
C
$ env A.B=C bash -c 'val=$(env | grep -oP "^A\.B=\K.*"); echo "$val"'
C
```