# How can I pass ARG with dots during docker build time?

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-maven-plugin

docker-compose.yml

```
...
args:
  project.version: 1.0.0
```

Dockerfile

```
ARG project.version
...
LABEL version=${project.version}
```

This throws the following error when I try to build the image through docker-compose.
failed to build : failed to process "${project.version}": missing ':' in substitution

If I replace project.version with project_version in both files then it fixes the issue.
However, I can't do that because I build this image through io.fabric8 docker-maven-plugin too and maven understands project.version and not project_version. Quite a dilemma! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Variables in bash only allow alphanumeric characters and under‐scores.

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753126/create-environment-variable-with-dot-in-the-current-environment) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93532/exporting-a-variable-with-dot-in-it).